# JAXB: marshal/unmarshal different XML elements to/from one class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, xmlbeans

Let's say, I have the following class:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Payment {
    @XmlElement
    int amount;
    @XmlElement
    Currency currency;

    @XmlElement
    IResponse response;
}
```

If `response==null` - the element is a "request", otherwise - the element is a "response".  When a request, the element should be (un)marshaled to (from) the root element called `PaymentRequest`, when a response - to (from) `PaymentResponse`.

How can I configure such marshaling algorithm? If JAXB can't do it, maybe some other engine can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally implemented the unmarshaling by intercepting StAX events. Here is the code:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootElement.class, A.class, B.class, C.class, D.class, E.class);
Unmarshaller unmarsh = jc.createUnmarshaller();
XMLStreamReader xs = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(etalonRs));
XMLStreamReader xd = new StreamReaderDelegate(xs) {
      public static final String ROOT_ELEMENT = "TestRoot";
      public static final int REPLACEABLE_LEVEL = 2;
      public final Collection<String> sufficesToDelete = Arrays.asList("Rq", "Rs");

      protected Stack<String> elementNamesStack = new Stack<>();
      protected Set<String> replaceableNames = new HashSet<>();

      @Override
      public String getLocalName() {
          String realName = super.getLocalName();
          if (replaceableNames.contains(realName) && elementNamesStack.size() == REPLACEABLE_LEVEL) {
              for (String suffix : sufficesToDelete) {
                  if (realName.endsWith(suffix)) {
                      return realName.substring(0, realName.lastIndexOf(suffix));
                  }
              }
          }
          return realName;
      }

      @Override
      public int next() throws XMLStreamException {
          final int eventCode = super.next();
         processLevel(eventCode);
          return eventCode;
      }

      @Override
      public int nextTag() throws XMLStreamException {
          final int eventCode = super.nextTag();
          processLevel(eventCode);
          return eventCode;
      }

      private void processLevel(int eventCode) {
          switch (eventCode) {
              case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
                  final String origElementName = super.getLocalName();
                  if ((elementNamesStack.size() + 1) == REPLACEABLE_LEVEL && elementNamesStack.peek().equals(ROOT_ELEMENT))
                      replaceableNames.add(origElementName);
                  elementNamesStack.push(origElementName);
                  break;
              case XMLStreamReader.END_ELEMENT: 
                  assert(elementNamesStack.pop().equals(super.getLocalName()));
                  break;

          }
      }
  };

Object o = unmarsh.unmarshal(xd);
```

Here are my test classes. Yes, the real structure in production is more complicated - there are different "payments" and their elements are not in the root,  so I've had to use the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "TestRoot")
public static class RootElement {
    @XmlElement(name = "SomeDate")
    private Date dt = new Date();

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    private A a = new C();
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "TestA")
@XmlType
public static abstract class A {
    private int fld1 = 1;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    @XmlElementWrapper
    protected List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "TestC")
public static class C extends A {
    private int fld2  = 3;
}
```

Marshaling can be implemented in the same manner, but you have to write your "StreamWriterDelegate" from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Create and marshal the root element like this:

```
JAXBElement<Payment> jbe;
if( payment.getResponse() != null ){
    jbe = wrap( null, "PaymentResponse", payment );
} else {
    jbe = wrap( null, "PaymentRequest", payment );
}
m.marshal( jbe, sw );
```

with the simple helper method

```
<T> JAXBElement<T> wrap( String ns, String tag, T o ){
    QName qtag = new QName( ns, tag );
    Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    JAXBElement<T> jbe = new JAXBElement( qtag, clazz, o );
    return jbe;
}
```

A simple way to make unmarshalling possible is to create two subclasses PaymentResponse and PaymentRequest which act as @XmlRootElements. The ObjectFactory contains

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "PaymentRequest")
public JAXBElement<PaymentRequest> 
createPaymentRequest(PaymentRequest value) {
    return new JAXBElement<PaymentRequest>(_Payment_QNAME, PaymentRequest.class, null, value);
}
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "PaymentResponse")
public JAXBElement<PaymentResponse> 
createPaymentResponse(PaymentResponse value) {
    return new JAXBElement<PaymentResponse>(_Payment_QNAME, PaymentResponse.class, null, value);
}
```

Unmarshalling:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( PACKAGE );
Unmarshaller m = jc.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<?> tb = null;
try {
    Payment payment = readFrom( Payment.class );
} catch( Exception e  ){
}
```

and the method readFrom:

```
public <T> T readFrom( Class<T> type ) throws Exception {
    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( PACKAGE );
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<T> jbe = (JAXBElement<T>)u.unmarshal( new File( XMLIN ) );
        return type.cast( jbe.getValue() );
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I see two issues here. During marshaling, you have to specify the name of the root element explicitly. And to implement the unmarshaling you need to change the structure of the classes (by creating different classes for requests and responses) - unfortunately, I can't do it. So, I've found another solution, please see the next answer.

Comment: The "different classes" for requests and responses are not affecting the remainder of the application, they aren't visible elsewhere.