# using one POJO class for different xml responses

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb

When I call rest service I get different xml responses, with different xml root element. I would like to know, are there any opportunities to unmarshal these xmls to one pojo class.

For example, I have a class RecordingCreated.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "recordingCreated")
public class RecordingCreated {

    private String nodeID;
    private String cameraID;
    private String recPath;
    private String recordingStatus;


    public String getNodeID() {
        return nodeID;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setNodeID(String nodeID) {
        this.nodeID = nodeID;
    }

    public String getCameraID() {
        return cameraID;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setCameraID(String cameraID) {
        this.cameraID = cameraID;
    }

    public String getRecPath() {
        return recPath;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setRecPath(String recPath) {
        this.recPath = recPath;
    }

    public String getRecordingStatus() {
        return recordingStatus;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setRecordingStatus(String recordingStatus) {
        this.recordingStatus = recordingStatus;
    }
}
```

After calling rest service I can get xml response in the form of

```
<recordingCreated>
    <nodeID>"111</nodeID>
    <cameraID>222</cameraID>\
    <recordingID>333</recordingID>\
    <recPath>rec</recPath>
    <recordingStatus>recorded</recordingStatus>
</recordingCreated>
```

And in the form of

```
<error>
    <code>444</code>
    <description>broker: access denied</description>
</error>
```

When I got first xml resposne, JAXB unmarshal good

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RecordingCreated.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
RecordingCreated recordingCreated = (RecordingCreated) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
```

But when I got second response, of course, I got an error, like this

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"",
>   local:"error"). Expected elements are <{}recordingCreated>]]

**Question:** Is there any opportunity having one class unmarshal two various xml responses with different root elements?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: 1. I don't want to create similar classes for different responses.
2. I don't know what response I get. So if i get second response and i try to unmarshal I have got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two different sub classes for your two different responses with their corresponding roots. 
You can have the current class as posted as the parent for both of them and depending on the response you would get, call the required class.

Comment: Can  you give example of code, I think you aren't right.

Comment: I was suggesting something like this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098330/jaxb-marshal-unmarshal-different-xml-elements-to-from-one-class/33148115